Run Multiple Commands As Admin From PS1 File ( Windows Terminal)
This PS1 File (test.ps1), while executed, will run The Commands Pushd $Home; bcdedit /enum bootmgr; pause As Admin in PWSH.exe its self.
# test.ps1
$AL = "-NoProfile -WindowStyle Maximized -ExecutionPolicy Bypass", 
      "-Command", "Pushd $Home; bcdedit /enum bootmgr; pause"
Start -Verb RunAs -FilePath pwsh.exe -ArgumentList $AL

What is the writing format, if I execute it (test.ps1), then will opened in Windows Terminal Elevated/ As Admin?
I tried:
# test.ps1
$AL = "-M -p 'PowerShell'", 
      "pwsh.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"Pushd $Home; bcdedit /enum bootmgr; pause`""
Start -Verb RunAs -FilePath wt.exe -ArgumentList $AL

giving the errors:
[error 2147942402 (0x80070002) when launching `" pause"']
[error 2147942402 (0x80070002) when launching `" bcdedit /enum bootmgr"']
I have also tried other formats but the error still persists.
Only works if one command:
# test.ps1
$AL = "-M -p 'PowerShell'", 
      "pwsh.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"bcdedit /enum bootmgr`""
Start -Verb RunAs -FilePath wt.exe -ArgumentList $AL


Windows Termimal has powershell in it. You don't need all the stuff. You can just do pushd $Home;bcdedit /enum...


@LPChip from CLI or ps1 file?


From Windows Terminal with a Powershell tab, directly in the cli. although you could technically type in the name of the .ps1 file and run it that way

Of course, I can open wt cli as admin and run some commands there. but what I'm asking is not from the cli, but from the ps1 file. Thanks.

I don't understand the question then.

perhaps the question unclear. i'll edit it.

Why nnot running your command with PS1 or .bat file ? You can open a .bat file via PS1if needed

-@Maslie Perhaps you can give me an example as answer. thanks.

In case this helps since the error is on pause, so rather than use pause, replace it with Read-Host -Prompt "Press any key to continue". This way it might work but test it out and see if it helps any.

-@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle  It seems that what is causing the error is not pause, but writing format for multiple commands. Sorry, question edited. I included both errors.


Unescaped ; on the wt.exe command line serve to separate multiple commands for Windows Terminal.
Therefore, ; characters to be passed through to a target executable must be escaped, namely as \;, which is unfortunately always necessary - even for ; characters inside (embedded) "...".

As of this writing, the linked documentation doesn't state this requirement; GitHub docs issue #763 aims to correct that.

Therefore:
$AL = "-M -p PowerShell -d `"$HOME`" " + 
      'pwsh.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -c "bcdedit /enum bootmgr\; pause"'
Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath wt.exe -ArgumentList $AL

Note:

For simplicity, the above uses wt.exe's -d option to pass a startup directory.
A single string encoding all arguments is passed to the -ArgumentList parameter, which is generally preferable to work around a long-standing bug that won't be fixed - see this SO answer.


So, just only need \ . Thank You. I have spent a lot of time looking for this solution.

My pleasure, @Mr.Key7; the need for \ isn't obvious, especially inside "..."

@mklement0 Thank you for helping on SU, we need your kind more often over here!!
